# windows 10 auto compose characters "built in"?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

On my new laptop, I see the following behavior new to me. If I press, e.g., the "-key, the '"' does not appear immediately. It changes how the next character appears, so "+a becomes ä, "+space becomes ", and so on.  I guess, this functionality is called composition (but for me, it does not involve the Compose key)

This behavior is present across all applications.  Furthermore, I have no application runing that provides it (like AllChars). Therefore, I guess it comes from the OS, i.e., Windows itself.

Is that right? How to control it? I couldn't find any switches.  It is helpful, but some special characters I cannot produce, like the German sz.
How to do that?

I have

- Windows 10 pro, Version 1803
- an English keyboard
- Country is Germany, Languages English (en-DE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is built in to Windows, but it's selectable/configurable.

It is likely that your default keyboard layout is set to US-International, rather than English-United States. This supports applying accents to characters, so that you can properly type most Western European languages.  The "dead keys" that double as accents are <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, and <kbd>^</kbd>, applying the grave, tilde, acute, umlaut, and circumflex accents respectively. To get the actual character, follow them with space instead of a letter that they can be applied to.

You *can* get the ß; hold down the *right* <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (which may or may not be marked <kbd>AltGr</kbd>), and press <kbd>s</kbd>. Note that the recently-defined upper-case ß is *not* available, however.

(I use this keyboard layout routinely, as I need to do multilingual document processing. I'm quite familiar with it, and can give you any other special characters you might need; just list them in an edit to the question or a comment, and I'll update this answer.)

Comment: Thanks, that clarified things. Now that I know what to look for, I found useful sites online